How should one compute the betweenness centrality for a graph with floating point edge weights?
For my work I apply dislocation dynamics, which is a modelling method used in materials science. In this model, dislocation lines are discretised so that the dislocation network can be simulated as a dynamic graph. In my model, the edges have weights corresponding to their Euclidean length. I am interested in computing several properties of this graph---one of these properties is the betweenness centrality (BC).
Suppose we have an undirected graph $G = \left( V, E \right)$. The betweenness centrality of a node $v \in V$ is given by the expression
\begin{equation}
BC(v) = \sum_{s \neq v \neq t \in V} \frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma_{st}$ is the number of shortest paths from node $s \in V$ to node $t \in V$. The length of a path is defined as the sum of the weights of the edges of that path. Each edge has a weight assigned by an edge function $\omega : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\omega(e) = 1$ for unweighted graphs, and  $\omega(e) > 0$ for weighted graphs.
I am familiar with what the elements of the computation for $BC(v)$ in an unweighted graph look like. Since the weight of each edge is unity, the length of a path is simply the number of edges along that path. I also understand the weighted variant, and that it generalises straight-forwardly.
My concern arises when considering an algorithm to compute the shortest path for the case when the edge weights are floating point numbers. Suppose that the average distance between two nodes in a given graph is a relatively large value such as $d_G = 10000$. Next, consider the case that there exists three paths between $s \in V$ and $t \in V$, with lengths given by $L_1 = 9.9998$, $L_2 = 10.001$, and $L_3 = 10000$. In the very strict algorithm (1), $$L_1 < L_2 < L_3$$ and thus there will be only one shortest path, namely $L_1$. This would result in $\sigma_{st} = 1$. However, the distance between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is very small compared to $L_3$, and so it would be reasonable to believe that this algorithm is too strict for many purposes. An alternative algorithm (2) would yield $$L_1 \approx L_2 < L_3$$ which would result in there being two shortest paths, i.e. $\sigma_{st} = 2$. This appears to me to be more reasonable.
It seems that this problem would arise essentially every time the shortest path is computed. This would result in $\sigma_{st} = 1$, and $\sigma_{st}(v) = 1$ or $\sigma_{st}(v) = 0$ depending on whether $v \in V$ lies on the single shortest path or not. Nevertheless, this may still be useful: using algorithm (1) to compute $BC(v)$ would still yield the fraction of shortest paths that $v$ lies on. However, lots of useful information could be left out in the form of paths of similar length. One solution to this problem seems to me to discretise the edge weights by rounding them to integers before inputting them into the BC computation which uses algorithm (1). Alternatively, when calculating the shortest paths, a tolerance can be used as in algorithm (2).
My question is then: how should this problem be treated? I can't seem to find a standard method of dealing with this issue. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?
